# MacBook Pro Battery Life Problems - only 2 hours with light usage

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

At some point in the past 2 weeks, my MacBook Pro (13", early 2011) began running hot and getting poor battery life.  The battery life used to last 4-5 hours even when I was using it regularly.  Now, it will die within 2 hours of idling.

When I say 'running hot' - I have noticed it on my lap and the fan comes on more often.

I have been checking Activity Monitor, but I cannot find a particular culprit.  Here is the battery info from running Coconutbattery.

```
Current Charge: 1068
Maximum Charge: 5292
Current Capacity: 5292
Design Capacity: 5770
Percent: 91%

Mac Model: MacBookPro8,1
Age of Your Mac: 15 Months
Battery Load Cycles: 320
Battery Temperature: 31.2 C
```

I uninstalled Chrome & Dropbox, which I thought might be the problem, but it still exists.  I've also calibrated my battery according to [these instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1490)

How do I begin to troubleshoot this problem?

UPDATE:

Found a culprit.  I haven't tested yet, so I'm not sure if this is THE culprit, or even if I've completely kicked it...

With some extensive googling, I found a bunch of users have issues with Adobe Version Cue CS3 or CS4.  I had CS3.  I made the HUGE mistake of uninstalling it manually (dragging system prefs to the trash).  This caused CrashReporter to run at > 100% CPU constantly and caused Console to light up with Bus Errors.

However, by right clicking the prefs pane and disabling it, I was able to get "launchd" down from 7-8% to 1-2%.

I'll update as I learn more.

Comment: My first guess would have been the battery itself, but at leasts the load cycles should be ok according to http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1519. OTOH if the problem persists after recalibration I would probably visit an Apple Store or Dealer nearby.

Comment: Is there any way to diagnose / troubleshoot the issue without taking it in?  The closest apple store is 3 hours away and I'd like to do what I can before taking it in..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, so I thought I'd update here in case anyone else has this issue.

I'm running a 13", MBP with OS X 10.6.8.  This problem will not present itself for previous versions of OS X but will likely appear in later versions.

A few weeks ago I installed some Adobe CS3 software - particularly the Design Suite, although I had later versions of photoshop and dreamweaver already installed.  As part of the CS3 suite, I installed Adobe Version Cue CS3.  This software does NOT play nice with OS X.

At first, I tried manually removing it (easier for most uninstalls in my opinion).  This was a big mistake.  When I deleted the preference files, my CPU began running at over 100% for "CrashReport".  This didn't stop until I restored via Time Machine (thank God for Time Machine!)

Secondly, I disabled it, which did lower launchd and others by 5% or so, but did not ultimately result in my machine running cooler, or my battery lasting longer.

Note: my fans would come on full speed even while the computer was idling!

Finally, I ran the complete Adobe uninstaller for CS3 suite which cleaned up my problem completely.  Turns out Adobe CS3 is [Unsupported for Snow Leopard](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=772907) although quietly.  You can barely find any mention of this on adobe.com and the software still seems to install quite fine.

Bottom line - if you have a Snow Leopard Macbook Pro - do NOT install Adobe CS3 software - in particular Version Cue.